# D3.js collapsable tree - visualise set number of levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, tree

I'm playing around with this example of collapsible tree: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

In this example initially only the root and all of its children are visualized. I was wondering how one could visualize set number of levels (for example the root and two additional levels, meaning the root, its children, and children of roots children).

I tried modifying `collapse(d)` function, in which I specified to collapse a node based on its `depth` property. Like:

```
function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children && d.depth > 3) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
    }
}
```

But then none of the nodes get collapsed, because `d.depth` property is `undefined`. I dug deeper and understood (correct me if I'm wrong) that `depth` property only gets assigned to a node after the `nodes` variable gets initialized.

`var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();`

Now I'm completely stuck. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my question. It turns out that nodes don't have parent, position (x, y coordinates), and depth attributes before `tree.nodes(root)` is called, which calculates all of the above mentioned attributes. So what I had to do is call that function **before** I call `collapse` function. After that it is possible to collapse only those nodes, that are of certain depth, which will visualize only certain number of levels.